# Создать новый DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame

df1['a'],df1['b'],df1['c'],df1['d']

df2['a'],df2['b'],df2['c'],df2['d']

Как создать новый столбец с данным

df1['new]

в котором будут браться значения

df1['a']/df2['a']

df1['b']/df2['b']

df1['c']/df2['c']

df1['d']/df2['d']

и выбираться максимальное значение из них?

Comment: На будущее: [как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
cols = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
df1["new"] = (df1[cols] / df2[cols]).max(axis=1)
```